# Print full path of files and sizes with find in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, find, ls

Here are the specs: Find all files in / modified after the modification time of /tmp/test, exclude /proc and /sys from the search, and print the full path of the file along with human readable size. Here is what I have so far:

```
find / \( -path /proc -o -path /sys \) -prune -o -newer /tmp/test -exec ls -lh {} \; | less
```

The issue is that the full path doesn't get printed. Unfortunately, ls doesn't support printing the full path! And all solutions I have found that show how to print the full path suggest using find. :|

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `-exec ls -lh {} \;` you can also use the `printf` option:

```
find / \( -path /proc -o -path /sys \) -prune -o -newer /tmp/test -printf "%s %p\n" | less
```

Although that will just print the size in bytes and not in the nice human-readable format `ls` supports.

Comment: +1 for POSIX and non-`ls` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add `-d` to the ls command.

```
find / \( -path /proc -o -path /sys \) -prune -o -newer /tmp/test -exec ls -lhd {} \; | less
```

That will also fix the problem you were bound to have with files showing up twice in your list.

Answer (score 0):

I too enjoy my fullpaths, so I've ended up creating few aliases just for such an occasion:

`alias ldf='ls $PWD/* -dF'
alias lfp='ls $PWD/* -daFc --group-directories-first'
alias lfh='ls $PWD/.* -daFc --group-directories-first'
alias lafp='ls $PWD/.* $PWD/* -daFc --group-directories-first'`

And just simply store 'em to $HOME/.bashrc (these already follow the syntax of .bashrc)
Though, if one wants to copy+paste the code to terminal (Not a recommended practice, but I'm not your guardian, so:) Here is a direct paste for .bashrc:

`echo "
alias ldf='ls $PWD/* -dF'
alias lfp='ls $PWD/* -daFc --group-directories-first'
alias lfh='ls $PWD/.* -daFc --group-directories-first'
alias lafp='ls $PWD/.* $PWD/* -daFc --group-directories-first'" >> ~/.bashrc`

All of these are basically for the same goal, with minor tweaks for specific purposes; like:
ldf=List Directorys Files,
lfp= List Full Path -organizing flag used,
lfh= List Full Hidden,
And last; for all the users and porpoises:
lafp = List All-Full Path(both hidden and regulars)

Comment: The day you need to use some other system or user, it *will* bite you.